# Unable to Organize Legend into Multiple Columns in PyQGIS

Tags: layouts

I'm facing an issue while creating a legend using PyQGIS. I am unable to add a legend with the following code:

```
legend_item = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend_item.setTitle("Legend")
legend_item.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
legend_item.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
transparent_color = QColor.fromRgb(255, 255, 255, 0)
legend_item.setBackgroundColor(transparent_color)
legend_item.setLinkedMap(map_item)
```

I have verified that map_item is not empty. Therefore, I had to resort to an alternative approach:

```
legend_tree = QgsLayerTree()
legend_tree.addLayer(data_layer)
legend_item.model().setRootGroup(legend_tree)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend_item)
```

Now, I have successfully added the legend. However, due to the large number of attribute items in my data_layer, the legend becomes very long. I would like to organize the legend into multiple columns, but using legend_item.setColumnCount(6) doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I solve this problem?